Montgomery multiplication, CIOS method
Montgomery reduction is an algorithm designed to perform fast modulo reductions: a %= n.
Montgomery multiplication is based on that, and performs fast modulo multiplications: (a * b) % n. Montgomery multiplication is very math-oriented and assumes that numbers can take any size, while in computing practice, this is not the case. The paper "Analyzing and Comparing Montgomery Multiplication Algorithms" presents an implementation called CIOS, which performs a reduction step after every word-sized multiplication, which bounds the numbers size, critical property if the implementation targets static memory, and as little as possible.
Assume n=2^448-2^224-1, prime that generates the field for Goldilocks, used for ECDH (X448) and digital signatures (Ed448). Assume a word size of 32-bits; thus, W=2^32. This fixes s=14. This is a paper-translation implementation in Python:
Precomputations:
# returns: b^-1 (mod p)
def inv(b, p):
    ...

n = 2**448 - 2**224 - 1
w = 2**32
s = 448 // 32

# n'[0] = -n^-1 (mod w)
NI = (-inv(n, w)) % w
# Output: NI=1

Word-restriction functions (C-style).
# returns Carry and Sum from: a + x*y + b
def cs(a, x, y, b):
    ...
# Encodes x to 's' little-endian word-sized elements representation
def tolimbs(x):
    ...
# Decodes x to an int()
def fromlimbs(x):
    ...

Finally, the algorithm:
narr = tolimbs(n)
def cios(a, b):
    a, b = tolimbs(a), tolimbs(b)
    t = [0 for _ in range(s + 2)]
    for i in range(s):
        C = 0
        for j in range(s):
            C, t[j] = cs(t[j], a[j], b[i], C)
        t[s+1], t[s] = cs(t[s], 0, 0, C)

        m = (t[0] * NI) % w
        C, _ = cs(t[0], m, narr[0], 0)
        for j in range(1, s):
            C, t[j-1] = cs(t[j], m, narr[j], C)
        C, t[s-1] = cs(t[s], 0, 0, C)
        t[s] = t[s+1] + C

    return fromlimbs(t[:-1])


For 2*3, this does not return 6, but:
726838724295606890549323807888004534353641360687318060281490199180450568486727868847628381608154428146047061595308393926166876356870155

What did I miss?

It's not supposed to return (a*b) mod n, it's supposed to return (a*b)* R^(-1) mod n, where R=2^448.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk You're right, I misunderstood. I suppose, then, the best way to get 6 is to perform cios(cios(2, 3), (R**2)%n)?

Yes, that's one way, and of course (R**2) % n is a constant that could be precomputed. The "normal" use of Montgomery multiplication is for doing many modular multiplications, like in modular exponentiation. In that case, the conversion strategy is a little different.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Thank you very much. I'm aware Montgomery multiplication is not the fastest for performing one single multiplication, I believe that would be Barrett reduction, but I was interested in the algorithm. Thanks again! Feel free to post this as your answer and I'll accept it :)
